# How does decoding in UTF-8 know the byte boundaries?

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

I've been doing a bunch of reading on unicode encodings, especially with regards to Python. I think I have a pretty strong understanding of it now, but there's still one small detail I'm a little unsure about.

How does the decoding know the byte boundaries? For example, say I have a unicode string with two unicode characters with byte representations of `\xc6\xb4` and `\xe2\x98\x82`, respectively. I then write this unicode string to a file, so the file now contains the bytes 
`\xc6\xb4\xe2\x98\x82`. Now I decide to open and read the file (and Python defaults to decoding the file as utf-8), which leads me to my main question.

How does the decoding know to interpret the bytes `\xc6\xb4` and not `\xc6\xb4\xe2`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The byte boundaries are easily determined from the bit patterns. In your case, `\xc6` starts with the bits `1100`, and `\xe2` starts with `1110`. In UTF-8 (and I'm pretty sure this is not an accident), you can determine the number of bytes in the whole character by looking only at the first byte and counting the number of `1` bits at the start before the first `0`. So your first character has 2 bytes and the second one has 3 bytes.

If a byte starts with `0`, it is a regular ASCII character.

If a byte starts with `10`, it is part of a UTF-8 sequence (not the first character).

Comment: Indeed, this is a well-documented, conscious design decision.  https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/utf-8-history.txt

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks, that's the link I was looking for!