# How does deserialising byte arrays to utf8 know when each character starts/ends?

Tags: c#, string, serialization, utf-8, deserialization

I am bit confused how networking does this. I have a string in C# and I serialise it to utf-8. But according to utf-8 each character takes up "possibly" 1 to 4 bytes.

So if my server receives this byte array over the net and deserialises it knowing its a utf8 string of some size. How does it know how many bytes each character is to convert it properly?

Will i have to include the total bytes for each string in the protocol eg:

```
[message length][char byte length=1][2][char byte length=2][56][123][ ... etc...]
```

Or is this unnecessary ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does decoding in UTF-8 know the byte boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113496/how-does-decoding-in-utf-8-know-the-byte-boundaries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 encodes the number of bytes required in the bits that make up the character. Read the description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8); only single-byte code points start with a zero bit. Only two-byte code points start with bits 110, only bytes inside a multi-byte code point start with 10.

Comment: Oh ! Wow did not know that. Thank you. Guess i bloated my messages for no reason !